# Adding form values into grid using extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

In my JavaScript file I have the following store variable:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
 var store2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {

 storeId : 'employeeStore',
 fields : [ 'firstname', 'lastname', 'age' ],
 data : [ {
 firstname : "Michael",
 lastname : "Scott",
 age : "7",
 }, {
 firstname : "Caroline",
 lastname : "Schrute",
 age : "2",
 }, {
 firstname : "Jim",
 lastname : "Halpert",
 age : "3"
 }, {
 firstname : "Kevin",
 lastname : "Malone",
 age : "4",
 }, {
 firstname : "Angela",
 lastname : "Martin",
 age : "5",
 } ]
     });
```

and a couple lines after in my panel i have a couple of form fields:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title : 'Person Info',
    labelWidth : 75,

    frame : true,
    bodyStyle : 'padding:5px 5px 0',
    width : 900,
    renderTo : Ext.getBody(),
    layout : 'column',
    // arrange fieldsets side by side
    items : [
            {

                // ***** Person Info*****
                // Fieldset in Column 1 - collapsible via toggle button
                xtype : 'fieldset',
                columnWidth : 0.5,
                title : 'Person Details',
                collapsible : true,
                defaultType : 'textfield',
                defaults : {
                    anchor : '100%'
                },
                layout : 'anchor',
                items : [
                        {
                            fieldLabel : 'First Name:',
                            name : 'PersonFirstName'
                        },
                        {
                            fieldLabel : 'Last Name:',
                            name : 'PersonLastname'
                        } 
  (etc...)
```

In this panel I also have a button that is suppose the store the values into a grid when clicked

```
{
                text : 'Add Person',
                xtype : 'button',
                // margin: '0 0 0 100',
                formBind : true,
                // only enabled once the form is valid
                disabled : true,
                handler : function() {

                    // write code to add all fields to the grid
                    var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                    var vals = form.getValues();
                    store2.add(vals);
                }

            },


            {
                xtype : 'grid',
                title : 'Family Details',
                store : Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
                columns : [ {
                    text : 'First Name',
                    dataIndex : 'firstname',
                    type : 'string'
                }, {
                    text : 'Last Name',
                    dataIndex : 'lastname',
                    type : 'string'
                }, {
                    text : 'Age',
                    dataIndex : 'age',
                    type : 'string',

                }, ],
                width : 400,
                forceFit : true,
                renderTo : Ext.getBody()
            } ]
```

When I press the button I'm not able to see the values in the grid. It's only returning an empty row.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to add the *proxy* config to your store and check once.
For more info check this example from sencha [here](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/docs/Ext.grid.Panel.1/viewer.html)
And also check whether your store is loaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell where exactly the problem. I would start as following:

1. Remove from the grid all the columns and stay with only one. (lastname for example)
   This step will check if the problem is occurred because mapping data to the state.
2. When you are clicking the button , use dummy data first in order to see that appending to the store is working.

   var objectCollection = new Array();

   var objectItem = new Object();

   objectItem.lastname = "TestName";

   objectCollection.push(objectItem);

   store2.loadData(objectCollection);
3. In addition , I see that you defined values in store , but do not use 'autoLoad' property.
   It should populated as true ('autoLoad:true').

Answer (score 0):

Form field names should match with the grid columns data index . in our case form field name of person first name is "name : 'PersonFirstName'" so data index of the grid column Firs name should be "PersonFirstName" or vice versa.